# Why am getting the following error when adjusting a glmm with the "glmmTMB" function and I try to obtain the confidence intervals?

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, glmmtmb, tmb

I am trying to run the following model:

```
Mm3znb<-glmmTMB(total~ Geopolitical-1 + offset(logha) + YearCollected + tmn + (tmn|Site/Plot), ziformula = ~1, data = mc3m, family="nbinom2")
```

but when I try to obtain the confidence intervals am getting this error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Does anyone know what this issue might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem that has been fixed very recently (June 2022) in the development version (`confint` wasn't working in models with more than one random effect; `(tmn|Site/Plot)` is implicitly two random effects, as it gets expanded to `(tmn|Site) + (tmn|Site:Plot)` internally).

If you can (you will need to install development tools - e.g. Xcode if you're on MacOS, Rtools if you're on Windows), install the development version via

```r
remotes::install_github("glmmTMB/glmmTMB/glmmTMB")
```

The [pkgdown page](https://glmmtmb.github.io/glmmTMB/) has a little more information about installing (if all else fails, contact the developers to see if they can make a recent binary package available).

Comment: After updating the version of R, installing the development version of glmmTMB and TMB via github, the error disappeared and I was able to obtain the confidence intervals. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it.